# Error renewing addMarker google Maps 2v

Tags: android, handler, google-maps-android-api-2, cycle, marker

Well I have been making a lot of attempts, to do a cycle of renewing the addMarker, of my google maps.

When I start the activity, the icon appear in the map, but when the function is called again in the thread I get error...

I don't know what I can do, I try to declare addMarker to a Marker var, and in the thread declare var.remove() and put another addMarker and I get the same error...

This is the map_activity xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
<include layout="@layout/opciones_menu" android:id="@+id/opciones_menu"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my map_activity class

```
public class Mapa_activity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.mapa_activity);
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
//var global for updating the lat and lon
global=((Global)getApplicationContext());


Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
renovarMarcador();
}
};

// After call for background.start this run method call
public void run() {
Message msgObj = new Message();
while(!Mapa_activity.this.isFinishing())
{
handler.sendMessage(msgObj);
try {
System.out.println("****30s");
Thread.sleep(30000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}//while
}
});
// Start Thread
background.start();  
//After call start method thread called run Method
}




@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
renovarmarcador();
}

public void renovarmarcador(){
mMap.clear();
Double lat, lon;
lat = Double.parseDouble(global.gety(String.valueOf(NID)));
lon = Double.parseDouble(global.getx(String.valueOf(NID)));
System.out.println("LAT: " + lat + "\nLON: " + lon);
// Creating a LatLng object for the current location
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));

// Showing the current location in Google Map
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
// Zoom in the Google Map
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
}
}
```

I want to know where is the problem ...

```
10-12 16:59:37.427  25539-25539/com.gpslocmex.locmex E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: { what=0 when=-1ms } This message is already in use.
            at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:285)
            at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
            at android.os.Handler.postAtTime(Handler.java:285)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.cm.c(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.cm.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.et.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.j.onTransact(SourceFile:167)
            at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.addMarker(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)
            at com.gpslocmex.locmex.Mapa_activity.renovarmarcador(Mapa_activity.java:218)
            at com.gpslocmex.locmex.Mapa_activity$4$1.handleMessage(Mapa_activity.java:161)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown out because you call `new Message()` once and send the message more than once.

```
public void run() {

    while (!Mapa_activity.this.isFinishing()) {

        Message msgObj = new Message();

        handler.sendMessage(msgObj);
        try {
            System.out.println("****30s");
            Thread.sleep(30000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//while
}
```

Comment: And how I fix it?, I been trying in different ways to do this cycle of renewing the marker...

Comment: @DarckBlezzer, maybe you can put the new Message() into the while loop.

Comment: @DarckBlezzer, that is fine.